# TinyMCE is adding &nbsp instead of the space when using the word paste

Tags: tinymce

I am using the TinyMCE editor and the paste from word function.

My problem is that when I have spaces, tinyMCE transform them in &nbsp and I would like to keep the normal space.

Is there a filtering function or something similar which can be used in tinyMCe.init which will do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found a soultion, I am not sure that's the proper one, but it works. In the tinyMCE.init, I added:

```
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
        // remove extra line breaks
        o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/ig, " ");
    }
```

Here is the entire tinyMCE init:

```
function addTinyMCE_Authors_AffiliationsWord() {
    jQuery('#dialog-authors_affiliations_parsing').tinymce({
        script_url: '/js/tiny_mce_3.2.7_jquery/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        width: "800px",
        height: "250px",
        mode: "textarea",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "paste",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "pasteword",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 :"",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 :"",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 :"",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom",
        valid_elements : "p",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
            // remove &nbsp
            o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/ig, " ");
         }
     });
}
```

ENJOY...

Comment: If you have multiple spaces between words and you change the nbsp to a regular space (without the correct css defined) then the multiple spaces will render as a single space and this will not be a viable solution.

Answer (score 6):

have you tried to add:
`entity_encoding: 'raw'` when initializing tinyMce? it helped in my case.

Regards.

Comment: this solution having another issue when adding spaces to the end of editor then it will ignore those spaces.