# TinyMCE converting space to &nbsp;

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am using TinyMCE 4 and in that, if I insert a space in the textarea between two word or characters and then check the source, the space converted to `&nbsp;`.

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36356048/4420468), but that only resolves the issue partially. This is because, if I enter a single space between two characters or words, then TinyMCE doesn't add `&nbsp;`, but if I add **two consecutive spaces** between two characters or words, then it makes the second space `&nbsp;`.

Any work around on this?

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE is adding hard spaces when you type multiple spaces into the editor - HTML does not show multiple normal whitespace characters so you can't get (per your example) two spaces between letters with just regular spaces. Using hard spaces for every other space allows content authors to use spaces within content and get a rendered result that matches what they type in the editor.

If you render that HTML without hard spaces there would just be one space between each set of characters regardless of how many spaces you put in the HTML source.

The net is that the editor is doing what it needs to do to allow you to see multiple spaces.

Comment: Thank you @Michael for the reply.  1. Can you please clarify what do you mean by " hard spaces", "normal whitespace" & "regular spaces"?

2. >>The net is that the editor is doing what it needs to do to allow you to see multiple spaces.<< Is there anyway to convert each space to &nbsp;?

Comment: A hard space is `&nbsp;`.  A regular space shows as just a space in the editor.  HTML does not render multiple regular spaces - this is not a TinyMCE issue its how browsers work. Why do you need to convert all spaces to `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I mean, I would like to convert all the &nbsp; to spaces. The thing is, I am displaying TinyMCE content in our website but because of &nbsp; in the content in place of space, CSS property word-break does not work well as, it thinks that it's continuous string. So if I have spaces in place of &nbsp; then that would break the content properly to the new line.

Comment: The editor won't do that as it would make the rendered content not look the same as what you see in TinyMCE.  You could try to modify when saving the content or on keypress but I don't think its going to do what your authors want.  How will they enter multiple if they need whitespace between characters?